# How do I print a range of data in awk?

Tags: apache, bash, awk, centos

I am reviewing my access_logs with a statment like:

```
cat access_log | grep 16/Sep/2012:17 | awk '{print $12 $13 $14 $15 $16}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40
```

The purpose is to see the user agent of the anyone that has been hitting my server for the last hour sorted by number of hits. My server has unusual activity to I want stop any unwanted spiders/etc.

But the part: `awk '{print $12 $13 $14 $15 $16}'` would be much preferred as something like: `awk '{print $12-through-end-of-line}'` so that I could see the whole user agent which is a different length for each one.

Is there a way to do this with awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not extremely elegant, but this works:

```
grep 16/Sep/2012:17 access_log | awk '{for (i=12;i<=NF;++i) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}'
```

It has the side effect of condensing multiple spaces between fields down to one, and putting an extra one at the end of the line, though, which probably isn't critical.

Comment: This also has the benefit over my answer of allowing you to eliminate the `grep` by moving the search text inside the `awk` script: `awk '/16\/Sep\/2012:17/ { ... }' access_log`.

Answer (score 2):

I've never found one; in situations like this, I use `cut` (assuming I don't need `awk`'s flexible handling of field separation):

```
# Assuming tab-separated fields, cut's default
grep 16/Sep/2012:17 access_log | cut -f12- | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40

# For space-separated fields (single spaces, not arbitrary amounts of whitespace)
grep 16/Sep/2012:17 access_log | cut -d' ' -f12- | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40
```

(Clarification: I've never found a *good* way. I've used @twalberg's for-loop when necessary, but prefer using `cut` if possible.)

Comment: wouldn't it be `cut -f12-` to get everything `awk '{print $12-through-end-of-line}'`, per the O.P. Dang, forgot about `cut`. Good solution!

Comment: Good point. I took the 12-16 literally, but `cut -f12-` would be preferred to get the entire rest of the line.

Comment: It seems to be space separated not tab separated. I like the idea but it didn't work.

Comment: @danielson317 I've updated my answer, but it will only work if there is exactly one space separating each field. `awk` is more flexible, in that it considers any amount of whitespace (composed of spaces, tabs, etc) to separate two fields.

Comment: Excellent. I already marked the other as the solution since it used awk but I voted you up.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo somefields:; cat somefields ; echo from-to.awk: ; \
  cat from-to.awk ; echo ;awk -f from-to.awk  somefields 
somefields:
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
from-to.awk:
{ for (i=12; i<=NF; i++) { printf "%s ", $i }; print "" }

l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 
12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
```

---

from man awk:

NF          The number of fields in the current input record.

---

So you basically loop through fields (separated by spaces) from 12 to the last one.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Every line in the file awk reads (or output from annother command such as grep) is a record. NF is the number of "fields" on every  line. In the example above the alphabet has 26 fields, the numbers line has 21 fields, and the file consists of 2 records.

Answer (score 0):

why not

```
  #!/bin/bash
  awk "/$1/"'{for (i=12;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s ", $i) ;printf "\n"}' log | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40
```

in a script file.

Then you can call it like

```
 myMonitor.sh 16/Sep/2012:17
```

Don't have a way to test this right. Appologies for any formatting/syntax errors.
Hopefully you get the idea.

IHTH

Comment: Good Idea on the script. I don't really do this enough to justify having to set all that up at the moment. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/16/Sep/2012:17/{for(i=1;i<12;i++){$i="";}print}' access_log| sort | uniq -c | sort -n | tail -40
```